# with structure: with remote Australian mine sites often long distances from professional emergency services

Tags: prepositional-phrases

> **With remote Australian mine sites often long distances from professional emergency services**, on-site emergency response crews need to feel confident handling just about any type of crisis.

I couldn't fathom the with structure here. Is there a rule(formular) here?

Answer (score 1):

What's between the "with" and the comma is the reason for what follows the comma. It's equivalent to "BECAUSE remote Australian mine sites ARE often long distances from professional emergency services".

There's a technical rule for everything. So, I suppose there's one for this. But I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of an exceptionally long prepositional phrase that has been moved to the start of the sentence and joined with a comma. The sentence could also have been written:

> On-site emergency response crews need to feel confident handling just about any type of crisis with remote Australian mine sites often long distances from professional emergency services.

I find it helpful to reduce sentences to their essential components and build them back up in order to understand their structure. In this case, it would go something like this:

> 1. Crews need to feel confident.
> 2. Crews need to feel confident *handling [a] crisis*.
> 3. Crews need to feel confident handling [a] crisis *with remote sites [being] long distances from services*.
> 4. With remote sites [being] long distances from services, crews need to feel confident handling a crisis.

The remaining words are all elaborating on the parts I included above: what kind of crews, what type of crisis, what kind of mine sites and how remote, etc.

The trickiest leap is from stage 2 to stage 3, mostly because the word "with" is used in an idiomatic way to mean something like "considering" or "given that".

Overall, this is an unwieldy sentence. Were I the editor for whoever wrote this, I might have suggested the following as an alternative:

> Because professional emergency services are often far away, on-site emergency response crews at remote Australian mine sites must be prepared to handle any type of crisis.